# How to replace each paragraph with anchor tag? Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to dynamically change every paragraph tag with anchor tag JQuery?
let's assume i have 3 paragraphs, how to change them to anchor tags with the content.

```
<div class="a">
   <p>1</p>
   <p>2</p>
   <p>3</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `replaceWith` of jQuery.

```js
function change(){
    $('p').each(function() {
      $(this).replaceWith($('<a href='+ $(this).text() +'>' + $(this).text() + '</a>'));
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="change()">Change To a Tag</button>
<div class="a">
   <p>1</p>
   <p>2</p>
   <p>3</p>
</div>
```